# Modelling indefinitely recurring events in an calendar?

Tags: android, calendar

I want to create an own calendar source (not an own calendar application, just an application filling some data in a new calendar added to CalendarContract.Calendars) with recurring events once a year, that however don't recurr at the same day, let's take `eastern` as an good example!

Now how could I modell e.g. eastern for an indefinite timespan? (calculating it is not the problem and also not my question here)

I could insert it to my calendar for the next 10 years, but then maybe a user jumps to year 2100 and complains that my calendar doesn't report eastern for that year - how to solve this problem?

- Do I have to insert eastern for the next 1000 years?
- Is there some kind of request from the android system to the calendar source by using some callback, telling me which month and year the user is currently looking for so I can check if eastern in that year is in the month the user is currently looking at and then I add an entry for eastern on the fly?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recurring event, with a frequency of one year, with no expiry. (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-event)

To check if a specific date will have this event, you can use the Instances table (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#instances) to query if a particular event happens within a time period.

Comment: I fear this won't work for eastern, because it's not at the same date every year!

Comment: Do the events happen at a specific interval? Or the interval changes as well?